# how to create 2 or more PDO objects in one php page?

Tags: php, object, pdo

Hi I have a code which there is a pdo object like this :

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$servername.'; dbname='.$db.';charset=utf8' , $db_username, $db_password);
```

thats good but When I want to creat another PDO object wiht a different name  i into same page like this :

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.$servername.'; dbname='.$db.';charset=utf8' , $db_username, $db_password);
$notification_array = $dbh -> prepare("select * from `machines`ORDER BY id DESC limit 51 ");
```

php says :

```
 Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDO could not be converted to string
```

I thoght maybe I must make last PDO object ($db) NULL ! 
like this :

```
$db = null;
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.$servername.'; dbname='.$db.';charset=utf8' , $db_username, $db_password);
$notification_array = $dbh -> prepare("select * from `machines`ORDER BY id DESC limit 51 ");
```

but by this way my  code does not work and does not read table
how can I create 2 simllar Pdo objects in a page ? I need it to keep them next to eachother

Comment: Rename variable of first PDO object.

Comment: what do you mean exactly ?

Comment: Database name stored in variable named $db.

Comment: You're re-using `$db`, the first as a connection, the second as the database name as @bbldzr said. Then you use it again in your new PDO connection. You need to change `dbname='.$db.'` in your first instance and your second instance.

Comment: @JayBlanchard tnx that;s it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in 
    `$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$servername.'; dbname='.$db.';charset=utf8' , $db_username, $db_password);`
you are using the same variable name `$db` for the pdo object and for the dbname
You should use
    `dbname='.$dbname`
for example.

Answer (score 3):

Name your first connection $con or something, as you're using the $db variable for your database name already.

If you're connecting to the same database, and judging by using the same variables it looks like you are, you don't need to close your connection and reopen it in between queries.

```
$con = new PDO($db,$name,$pass);
$con->query();
//do what you want with your query

$con->query();
//and then just move on to your next query
```